# i want to change color of students label according to marks from input text-box but there is problem in my java-script code

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Student One" class ="student">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Student Two" class ="student">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Student Three" class ="student">

    <br>
    <label style="font-size: 30px;">Student One</label><br>
    <label style="font-size: 30px;">Student Two</label><br>
    <label style="font-size: 30px;">Student Three</label><br>

    <button>Check</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var students = document.querySelectorAll(".student");
    var label = document.querySelectorAll("label");
    var button = document.querySelector("button");

    button.addEventListener("click",function(){
        for(var i = 0; i < students.length; i++){
            for(var j = 0; j < label.length; j++){
                if (students[i].value >= 70 && students[i].value <= 100){
                    label[j].style.backgroundColor = "green";
                }else if (students[i].value >= 50 && students[i].value < 70){
                    label[j].style.backgroundColor = "blue";                
                }else if (students[i].value >= 35 && students[i].value < 50){
                    label[j].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
                }else{
                    label[j].style.backgroundColor = "red";
                }
            }
        }
    });     
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

There is HTML which Contains Three Input box to enter marks of Three students.

There is three label which has text and one button is also to run javascript code

Now selecting of elements is works fine

**in java-script i used two For loop 
first is to loop for student[i]
second is to loop for label[j]**

When i try to debug it with console.log i see there is some mistake in for loops

Please Try To help me to solve this.

Comment: Please share your markup too.

Comment: <input type="text" placeholder="Student One" id="student">
<input type="text" placeholder="Student Two" id="student">
<input type="text" placeholder="Student Three" id="student">

Comment: <br>
 <label style="font-size: 30px;">Student One</label><br>
 <label style="font-size: 30px;">Student Two</label><br>
 <label style="font-size: 30px;">Student Three</label><br>

Comment: Please, not this way! Edit your question and paste there as a formatted code!

Comment: Anyway, `id`attribute is meant to be unique in the document. You can, however, use it many times, but don't be surprised if it causes problems. That `student` should be `class`, not `id`. I don't know where this code is placed, but the variables are declared outside, they might well not be populated at the point they are executed, thus the function could get empty arrays. But this all is bad-bad-bad practice...

Comment: i want add formatted code but it's continuously shows "Please add some context to explain the code sections (or check that you have not incorrectly formatted all of your question as code)."

Comment: Yes, you can't paste *just* code. You should explain your problem. You have only one non-code paragraph. That is not enough.

Comment: hey, Please check it out i re-edit the code and also provide some information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your solution with just one for loop

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title></title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Student One" class ="student">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Student Two" class ="student">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Student Three" class ="student">
            <br>
            <label style="font-size: 30px;" id="student-1">Student One</label><br>
            <label style="font-size: 30px;" id="student-2">Student Two</label><br>
            <label style="font-size: 30px;" id="student-3">Student Three</label><br>
            <button onClick="checkMarks();">Check</button>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var students = document.querySelectorAll(".student");
                function checkMarks(){
                    for(var i = 0; i < students.length; i++){
                       if (students[i].value >= 70 && students[i].value <= 100) color = "green";
                       else if (students[i].value >= 50 && students[i].value < 70) color = "blue";
                       else if (students[i].value >= 35 && students[i].value < 50) color = "yellow";
                       else color = "red";
                       document.getElementById('student-'+(i+1)).style.backgroundColor = color;
                    }
                }           
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Tell me if you need any help...

Answer (score 0):

```html
<table border>
   <tr>
      <th>Student</th><th>Mark</th>
   </tr>
   <tr data-student="1">
     <td class="label">Student one</td>
     <td><input type="number" min="0" max="100" /></td>
   </tr>
   <tr data-student="2">
     <td class="label">Student two</td>
     <td><input type="number" min="0" max="100" /></td>
   </tr>
   <tr data-student="3">
     <td class="label">Student three</td>
     <td><input type="number" min="0" max="100" /></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td colspan="2" ><button>Do work</button></td>
   </tr>
</table>
<script>
  var scale=[
      {color:'green',max:100,min:70},
      {color:'blue',max:70,min:50},
      {color:'yellow',max:50,min:35}
  ];
  document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    document.querySelectorAll('tr[data-student]').forEach(function(row){
      var mark = row.querySelector('input').value;
      var color = 'red';
      for(var i=0;i<scale.length;i++){
        if(mark > scale[i].min && mark<=scale[i].max) {
          color = scale[i].color;
          break;
        }
      }
      row.querySelector('.label').style.backgroundColor = color;
    });
  });
</script>
```

This is one possible approach. Remember: I don't want to make your homework - your requirements might be different. Nobody here will do it for you. But you might get some ideas from this solution.

To directly answer your question: the nested for loops were your problem here, as removing them does the job:

```
button.addEventListener("click",function(){
        for(var i = 0; i < students.length; i++){
            if (students[i].value >= 70 && students[i].value <= 100){
                label[i].style.backgroundColor = "green";
            }else if (students[i].value >= 50 && students[i].value < 70){
                label[i].style.backgroundColor = "blue";                
            }else if (students[i].value >= 35 && students[i].value < 50){
                label[i].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
            }else{
                label[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank You for your support :) i'm started to learn java-script so it help me a lot.

Comment: yes it works perfectly when removing nested for loop Thank You for your help :)